# Can there be a sequence which is not convergent but has accumulation points?

Tags: real-analysis

The sequences which are convergent are inevitably bounded. So, they have bound points and hence have accumulation points.

But at one place, my book mentions that it is not necessary for a sequence to be convergent or bounded for having accumulation points. Is it true?

Is there no relation between bounding of sequence & accumulaion points?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An accumulation point is a limit of some subsequence. Take
$$a_n = \begin{cases} n & n \text{ odd} \\ 0 & n \text{ even}\end{cases} = (1,0,3,0,5,\ldots)$$
It has $0$ as an accumulation point but is clearly neither convergent nor bounded.

Comment: Can you please tell me what subsequence is? I am new in this topic. Thanks in advance,

Comment: A subsequence $b_n$ of a sequence $a_n$ is such that there is a monotonically increasing sequence $(i_k) \subset \mathbb N$ such that
$$b_k = a_{i_k} \qquad \forall k$$
(In other words, $b_n$ is obtained by striking some elements from $a_n$)
In this case the sequence $(0,0,0,\ldots) = a_{2k}$ is a subsequence wich converges to $0$.

Comment: BTW, sir, can you tell me the difference between limit point & accumulation point? One says they are the same while the others say the different.

Comment: @user36790 To me they are equivalent, at least in a metric space such as $\mathbb R$. [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Limit_point) also uses them synonymously. I suggest you ask those who claim otherwise.

Comment: "A number $l$ is said to be a limit point of a sequence $u$ if every neighborhood $N_l$, of $l$ is such that $u_n \in N_l$, for infinitely many values of $n \in N$, i.e. for any $ε>0$, $u_n \in (l−ε,l+ε)$, for finitely many values of $n \in N$. Evidently, if $l = u_n$, for infinitely many values of $n$ then $l$ is a limit point of the sequence $u$." Is it in agreement with your definition of accumulation point, sir?

Comment: @user36790 Yes, these infinitely many values within $l\pm\varepsilon$ can be used to form a convergent subsequence.

Answer (score 0):

Look at cesaro summibility, you get few ideas by knowing that convergence in the sense of your book is only the classical convergence. If one considers partial sums as a sequence then you would see that unbounded sequences can still converge in a sense e.g. [see this vide](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=w-I6XTVZXww) and [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0Oazb7IWzbA)